# EM bound for factor analysis, imaginary?

Tags: factor-analysis, expectation-maximization

I am implementing factor analysis using EM. I get the likelihood, always increasing as expected. However, when I try to get the lower bound for which we have a closed form that allows us to keep maximising iteratively, that bound results to be an imaginary number, and it is not always increasing, so I imagine that I should have some error in the code. 
Basically, I compute the bound as:

$$B = \sum_{i=1}^{I} \int q(h_i|\theta) \log \frac{Pr(x_i,h_i|\theta)}{q(h_i|\theta)}dh_i$$

x is the data, h are the hidden variables and $\theta$ are the parameters.
In the model,

$$x_i = \mu + \Phi h_i + \epsilon$$

$$h_i = \epsilon$$

then,

$$Pr(x,h|\theta) = {Norm}_{xi}(\mu+\Phi h_i, \Sigma) {Norm}_{h_i}(0, I)$$

Which I sample separately instead of computing the resulting Gaussian. That is OK, right?

and

$$q(h_i) = Pr(h_i | x_i, \theta)$$

with mean

$$E[h_i] = (\Phi^T \Sigma^{-1} \Phi + I)^{-1} \Phi^T \Sigma^{-1}(x_i - \mu)$$

(I am following the same notation as Prince in [*Computer Vision: Models, Learning, and Inference*](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf). Page 127)

I have traced a bit the issue and sometimes, $x_i$ is smaller than the mean, so the expectation is negative.

Then, when the part inside the logarithm is therefore negative, and I get those complex numbers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please explain your notation. What is $\phi, \Sigma, \dots$. Also, giving a link to the book and the page/section number would be helpful in understanding the question. That said, the argument of the $\log$ function is the ratio between two probability values which must always be positive. BTW, do you make sure that $q(h_i | \theta)$ is non-zero?

Comment: Thanks Sobi. I will check this non-zero issue, it may give problems and I don't see how it is checked.